# Help with coding doors on a game im making in BGE

Tags: game-engine

I am trying to add a mechanism to open and close doors. What I am trying to do is create an amnesia style open/close mechanism. For those of you who don’t know how amnesia works, you open doors by holding down left mouse and dragging the mouse back and forth to move the door open and closed.

The only problem is we don’t know how to do anything like that at all.

Comment: what is the " amnesia style open/close" ?

Comment: http://blenderreal.com/door-interaction-bge-tutorial/

Comment: check [this file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/202/) it has a basic idea